# JSON returned AJAX post jQuery undefined

Tags: ajax, json, validation, jquery-mobile, jsonlint

I am using jQuery to get a list of Names as JSON string -

`

```
$.ajax({ type: 'POST', url: "../Names.aspx", dataType: 'json', contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", data: "NAME=ALL_PROFILES", success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR)` {

                var html = '';


                var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
                $.each(obj, function (key, val) {
                    html += '<option value="' + val + '">' + val + '</option>';
                    alert("Success" + val);
                })
                $('#selName').append(html);
                $('#selName').selectmenu('refresh');


            },
                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert('Error ' + jqXHR.val + errorThrown.val + textStatus.val);
                }
            });
```

The back end is an asp.net page, and when I debug I get the string as `"{"Name":["Maria","John","Raj","Rosh","Tony","Name","test3","test4","test5","test6"]}"`, which I put in [JSONLint](http://www.jsonlint.org) and validated. It returns an `undefined` error in the AJAX request above. If I try with a single string `"Name":"John"`, it works perfectly. The function for adding option is not correct for an array of JSON strings(I will work on it once it enter the success block), but I don't understand why it returns an `undefined` error when it is returning a valid JSON string. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put an extra paranthesis around the result and it works.It is strange since JSONLint is not validating it now

Answer (score 0):

If your aspx page returns valid JSON and you are using `dataType: 'json'`, you should not use `jQuery.parseJSON()` on the returned data, since jQuery already parses the returned JSON string into an object.

If you use `"Name":"John"` it is not valid JSON, so JQuery enters the `error` callback.

Comment: I think you are mistake.WHen I use "Name":"JOHN" it enters the success block.parseJSON is in Sucess block.It is not getting called anyways

Comment: Just make sure you return valid JSON and remove the line: `var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);` and work/loop on the `data` variable instead, this should work.

Comment: I have tried that.In fact I just put an alert in success block.It is not getting called at all

Comment: Are you sending your POST request to a different domain/subdomain, from what your HTML/jQuery code is running from?

Comment: No.its the same domain.I am getting the result when i return just one value for name.

Comment: Try looping on `data.Name` instead of `data`, like this: `$.each(data.Name, function (key, val) {`

Comment: I think I got it working.I put an extra paranthesis around the result and it works.It is strange since JSONLint is not validating it now.Thanks for your help anyways..:)